Determining average speed in still water taking account of the speed of the stream
Please can you clarify whether it is possible to derive an approximation of boat speed in still water from a boat’s speed upstream and downstream by making allowance for resistance that presumably varies with the square of the boat’s speed through the water. Ideally, express speed as pace (mm:ss/500m). The solution should give an estimate of speed in still water that is better than taking the average of upstream and downstream pace.
Presumably
$$R_\text{downstream} = f (u_\text{dowmstream})^2 \\ R_\text{upstream} = f (u_\text{upstream})^2$$
where
$$u_\text{downstream} = v + u_\text{stream} \\ u_\text{upstream} = v - u_\text{stream}$$
where $v$ = velocity in still water (to be solved for).
Assume constant stream velocity and power applied to the boat is constant.
I assume time t_u and t_d for a fixed distance (say, 500m) upstream and downstream must also be required.
Hope that appeals to someone with better physics than I have.

Since you have not responded to my answer, is there anything that you disagree with in it, or is there something that I have not made clear?

I hope my earlier response is visible. Thanks for your thoughts. Definitely I’m still struggling with this. .

I think you missed the point of my answer. For a given throttle setting, the speed on still water is equivalent to $ (V_{us} + V_{ds})/2$, relative to the shore of the river.  The $v^2$ water resistance factor plays no part in this calculation and should be forgotten.  If for example your upstream velocity is 10 km/hr and your downstream velocity is 20 km/hr then your still water equivalent speed is (10+20)/2 = 15 km/hr.  If you were to plan a round trip to a point 15 km upstream and then immediately return downstream to where you started, the round trip time would be 2 hours.

Once you have calculated a still water speed, it is applicable on any day, even when the river flow is different as long as the flow does not exceed the boats still water speed, so that it actually makes headway upstream.

“think you missed the point of my answer” Correct. I did. Thanks.

It turns out that the maximum speed of the boat relative to still water is pretty accurately represented by the average of it maximum upstream and downstream speeds, both measured relative to the shore.
While the resistance of the water is roughly proportional to $v^2$ the velocity v used here is the speed of the boat relative to the water itself and not the velocity relative to the shore.
$$V_{average} = \frac{(v + u_{stream}) + (v - u_{stream})}{2} = v$$
It can be seen from the formula above that we don't even need to know the velocity of the river ($u_{stream}$) relative to the shore. ($v + u_{stream}$) is the velocity of the boat downstream, relative to the shore and ($v - u_{stream}$) is the velocity of the boat upstream, relative to the shore.
Basically we are just transforming to a reference frame comoving with the water in the river. To see why the average sped is the correct answer consider the boat moving at maximum speed on a still lake. A helicopter hovers over the water and is stationary relative to the shores and the water surface. It takes a video of the boat that is moving East to West and the speed of the boat v can easily be determined from the video. Now the measurement is repeated with the helicopter moving East with speed $u_E$ and repeated again with the helicopter moving West with speed $u_W = -u_E$. The speed of the boat relative to still water is now the average of ($v+u_E$) and (v - u_E). Nothing about the motion of the helicopter changes the motion of the boat relative to the water, so no $v^2$ terms have to be considered. This is equivalent to the method of measuring the average of the upstream and downstream speeds.
There are some assumptions here, such as the river flow not being too choppy as that introduces wave friction. The resistance of water to the motion of a boat is actually quite a complex calculation involving around ten factors, but that is not important in the above calculation of average speed. For high speeds, air resistance and wind speed might start to become significant.

Ideally express speed as pace (mm:ss/500m)

If you have the speed (v) in meters/second, then to get pace (p) in seconds/500meters, use $$p = \frac{500}{v}.$$
I'm guessing you have already actually done measurements in terms of (mm:ss/500m). To convert that pace to v in terms of m/s, use $$v = \frac{500}{mm\times 60+ss} \  m/s. $$

It turns out that the maximum speed of the boat relative to still water is pretty accurately represented by the average of it maximum upstream and downstream speeds, both measured relative to the shore.
While the resistance of the water is roughly proportional to v2 the velocity v used here is the speed of the boat relative to the water itself and not the velocity relative to the shore.

Thanks for this. Delayed response due to being out in a boat on the water! (And technical issues).
(1) so the advice is to use maximum speed, in preference to average?
